# how to redirect to default page on logout

Tags: asp.net

i have a masterpage which contains loginstatus control

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
                     LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="Default.aspx" />
```

now on logout click i want to redirect the page to default.aspx but it is not working

Comment: What happens when you logout? Not working means?

Comment: when i logout it redirects to next page rather than default

Comment: next page?? what next page? please explain....

Comment: in my logged in page, on page load i have redirected it to next page so i guess when i click to logout then because of page load it goes to next page

Comment: What happen when you remove the redirect code?

Comment: the page get refreshed and remain the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been playing around with the login controls recently too and the only difference between what I have and yours is the "~/" in the logoutpageurl property.  So try this;

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
     LogoutAction="Redirect"
     LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ohh thnx actually i did try this but my problem was different and i thought this is not working,thnx for the response

Comment: This redirects me to "default.aspx?" all lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

Try placing this in your web.config file.

```
<location path="default.aspx">  
  <system.web>  
    <authorization>  
      <allow users="*"/>  
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>  
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the logoutAction attribute and set it to redirectToLoginPage

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" />
```

that's suppose that in your web.config you add :

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
```

the logout action will redirect you then to the loginUrl.

if you want to redirect to specific url you set logoutAction to redirect and you specify whatever url you want.